# How to make a column of categorised group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a column of “food” (apple, banana, carrot, donuts, egg,...), I want to make the “category” column that contains values which correspond to each item in “food” column.

Ex. given the information below

```py
import pandas as pd

fruit =['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
veg =['carrot', 'onion']
meat=['chicken', 'pork', 'beef']

food = fruit + veg + meat

df = pd.DataFrame(food, columns=['food'])
df
```

When I write the code like this:

```py
df[df['food']=='apple']['category']='fruit'
df[df['food']=='carrot']['category']='vegetable'
```

However, a `SettingWithCopyWarning` occurs when I write down in this way.

What would be the best way to set this value?

Comment: have a look at [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map)

Comment: Your question could be better formatted. Include a fully contained example, and use code blocks to separate code from text. Also clearly provide the error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and editing my question. turned very understandable. I will try posting questions to make myself understood clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably got a [SettingWithCopy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) warning from pandas. You can resolve that in a few different ways:

```py
# Use loc
df['category'] = None # Initialize an empty column
df.loc[df['food']=='apple',  'category'] = 'fruit'
df.loc[df['food']=='carrot', 'category'] = 'vegetable'

# Use map
df['category'] = df['food'].map({
    'apple': 'fruit',
    'carrot': 'vegetable'
})
```